# ¿Como hacer para tener Angular 10 y AngularJS al mismo tiempo?

Tags: angularjs

Actualmente utilizo la version de Angular 10, pero necesito hacer un proyecto desde 0 con AngularJS. Mi pregunta es ¿como hacer para tener 2 versiones de Angular al mismo tiempo sin que afecte a la version Angular 10?.

Comment: ¿Lo preguntas por la versión global del CLI? En el caso más extremo se me ocurre que puedes resolverlo haciendo imágenes de docker para cada projecto. Ona forma fácil es usar `npx` para invocar el CLI desde los módulos instalados en el proyecto y así tendrías aislado por proyecto la versión de angular y los otros módulos.

Comment: Gracias @EduardoHernández, no entiendio mucho, ya que para cada proyecto de Angular 10 hago un ng new nombreDeProyecto e instala todo de forma automatica, pudiendo arrancar el proyecto con ng serve etc..Viendo ahi AngularJS que es la version vieja pareciera que todo esto no se usa de la misma forma.

Comment: No. La versión vieja no se usaba así. Para la versión vieja descargabas/instalabas el framework y después todo lo hacías a mano. El CLI de angular es parte de las versiones angular.io. Tal vez el tutorial "viejo" te ayude un poco https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.

Comment: Gracias @EduardoHernández